# Assign if not null or if not set in Java

Tags: java

I am really tired of doing all the *if null* checks, resp. I also want to have a more configurable scenario for this. Let me explain this by an example:

I have a `getter()` which may return `null` or `'0'` in both cases the resp. `setter()` should not be called passing the `getter()`.

So the implementation is

```
if(getter() != null && !getter().equals('0')) setter(getter());
```

this however really anoys me, especially if `getter()` and `setter()` are really long method calls and I have to introduce helper variables for this.

I am thinking about a method with parameter

```
ifNotSet(getter(), setter(), new Object[null, '0']);
```

which does exactly the same thing. Where the parameters to ifNotSet are

- **getter** - the method to check if it does not equal one of the  **conditions**
- **setter** - the method to call in the way `setter(getter)` if **conditions** does not apply
- **conditions** - the conditions which must not apply on evaluation of `getter()` for the method to be executed

At first sight this does not seem to complicated, it however is! Is anyone aware of a solution to this problem or any kind of implementation?

Thanks!

**Update**

I've been working some more on the problem, after the feedback of you guys, and found out about the following

```
    private boolean ns(Object[] condition, Object getter) {
    boolean ret = false;
    for (Object object : condition) {
        if(getter) equals or == ??
    }
    return true;
}

    Object[] cond = new Object[] { null, "0" };
    Object a;
if (ns(cond, a = getter()))setter(a);
```

Well, this seemed to be at least a solution if you have a lot of allocations to do. However, if you take a look at the `ns()` method... the question on the incoming conditions is, whether to use `==` or `equals` to do the comparison!?

Comment: "I am really tired of doing all the if null checks" -- have a look at Groovy and its "safe navigation" operator ("?."). http://groovy.codehaus.org/Operators#Operators-SafeNavigationOperator

Comment: why not make a `isNullOrZero(x)` method? So, `if (!isNullOrZero(getter()) setter(getter());`

Comment: => Thanks to Scala for bringing getOrElse method from Option type :) ...   No null object and no ugly code as Java has .. ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can use this way

```
  public boolean checkNotNullOrZero(String s)
    {
    return (s!=null) && !s.equals("0");
    }
```

Basic use:

```
if(checkNotNullOrZero(getter()))
{
setter(getter());
}
```

Comment: hmm, but this way I would have to implement a checkNotNullOrZero for each setter() I have, wouldn't I? So it's not generic at all if bot setter and getter methods change all the time!

Answer (score 1):

You can't do what that as in Java methods are not first-class citizens. You could use reflection or anon classes but it would be way more work .

If null and zero are always equivalent for `getter` then could that be changed to return just one of the two?

If null and zero are always equivalent for `setter` then could that be changed to normalize the two?

Could you create a method `isNullOrZero(x)` then you can have

```
if (!isNullOrZero(getter())) {
  setter(getter());
}
```

Comment: same here, I would have to implement the method for each getter() which does not short-cut anything :( thx for the feedback, appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Ugly way of doing this literally in Java:

```
public interface Getter {
    public Object get();
}

public interface Caller {
    public void call();
}

public void callIfNotNull(Getter getter, Caller caller, Object[] nullObjects) {
    Object value = getter.get();
    for(Object nullObject : nullObjects) {
        if(value==nullObject) {
            return;
        }
    }
    caller.call();
}
```

Usage:

```
callIfNotNull(new Getter() {
        @Override
        public Object get() {
            return getterMethod();
        }
    }, new Caller() {
            @Override
            public void call() {
                setter();
            }
        }, new Object[]{null, '0'});
    }
```

You might need to implement sane way to check for null objects and give reasonable names.

Personnaly, I wouldn't go with this approach. I would try to implement [Null Object pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) to resolve an issue.

Comment: Much more work! I see doesn't make much sense to implement as it does not short-cut the problem :) thx however for the feedback +1 will have a look at the pattern!